# SendInput ExtraInfo / Flags

Tags: c#, flags, sendinput

I'm trying to use the SendInput api for a hotkey application. So what I'm doing is having a global keyhook, and when some keycombination hits I want to send another key instead.

My problem is that when I send the simulated keys, then my hook receives that message and I end up with a recursive loop.

So, I have tried using the ExtraInfo / Flags, but for some reason the value I set isn't the same that I receive in the hook.

```
var down = new INPUT();
down.Type = (UInt32)InputType.Keyboard;
down.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
down.Data.Keyboard.KeyCode = (UInt16)keyCode;
down.Data.Keyboard.Scan = 0;
down.Data.Keyboard.Flags = 0; //doesn't matter whatever I set here... never gets back to my hook
down.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
down.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero; //doesn't matter whatever I set here... never gets back to my hook
```

No matter what I set on the ExtraInfo / Flags ... it's reset when I receive the message in my hook:

```
    private IntPtr KeyStateChangeCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref KEYBDINPUT lParam)
    {
       //lParam.ExtraInfo and lParam.Flags ... is always some mumbo jumbo value or zero...
    }
```

I'm using the lowlevelkeyboard hook, "WH_KEYBOARD_LL" with setup like this:

```
        proc = KeyStateChangeCallback;
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            hookID = NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, NativeMethods.GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
```

Anyone else had a similar issue and could help me out? Any working code sample would be fantastic :)

Comment: What kind of hook are you using?

Comment: Thanks :) I'm using the WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook, have a look at the post again - updated it with additional information.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should call [GetMessageExtraInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) get retrieve the data in the `ExtraInfo` field.

Comment: Thanks, thats actually the solution I have been using so far, but I'm thinking it would be much safer to pass the values along with the message itself - since using GetMessageExtraInfo requires you to use the SetMmessageExtraInfo, which can't be used on "per input" basis... only on per whole message, while a message can consist of several inputs, "key presses" such as - "Key A Down", "Key B Down", "Key A Up" etc... and what about the issue with the Flags? Apparently there is no Set/Get combination for the flags right?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it works sending the ExtraInfo when running the application in x64 mode but not in x86. (the computer is x64 too) So it would seem one of the structures is incorrect... but I can't figure out which...